# Understanding the field of order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, abelian-groups, p-groups

So I understand that for any prime $p$, there exists a field of order $p^2$. What's confusing me, is that a field is also an abelian group, and the only abelian groups of order $p^2$ up to isomorphisms are $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, neither of which are fields. Can anyone please help me wrap my head around how its possible for a field of order $p^2$ to both be an abelian group of order $p^2$, and simultaneously not be isomorphic to any abelian group of order $p^2$ that exists?

Comment: The additive group of the field has $p^2$ elements; the multiplicative one has $p^2-1$

Comment: Well, the isomorphism is only for the additive structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime. Then the field with $p^2$ elements has the underlying additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

You state that $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is "not a field," and indeed it is not when you view it with the standard multiplication entrywise in each component. But the field with $p^2$ has a different multiplication structure which allows you to turn the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ into a commutative ring where every nonzero element is invertible with respect to this multiplication.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain that the phenomenon is the same as when you work over $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$: as abelian groups, $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ but the multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$ is more subtle than something just coordinatewise.